# Scanner EOF handling for user input

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner, infinite-loop, eof

I'm developing a console application and as such I must be able to handle any user inputs, but when you enter an EOF character I cannot resolve the Scanner's bizarre behavior.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] options = {"Login", "Register", "Quit"};
    while(true){
        for(int i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ": " + options[i]);
        try {
            switch(Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())){
                case 0:
                    login();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    register();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return;
                default:
                    System.out,println("must be between 0 and " + (options.length - 1));
            } catch(NumberFormatException | NoSuchElementException e){
                System.err.println(e.getMessage);
                if(DEBUG)
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

This appears to work to cover any malformed input a user might try, but when I enter my EOF character the Scanner will infinitely throw the NoSuchElementException instead of consuming EOF and prompting the user for new input. I know what EOF is, but as a user can input it, I should have handling for it that allows the app to still run.

How can I get scanner to consume the EOF token and continue reading further user input?

Comment: As you know, EOF means End-Of-File, and when `System.in` receives such a character, it closes the input stream. Once closed, it cannot be re-opened.

Comment: How then do I restore the program to a point before user inputs EOF? Scanner must behave differently cause with other streams I can open a new stream by a new instance of that stream, but new instances of scanner also infinitely throw the NoSuchElementException

Comment: You can't. The user has said: "There will be no more input", so there *will* be no more input, even if user changes his/her mind. --- The problem isn't `Scanner`, but `System.in`. This has nothing to do with `Scanner`, and creating new `Scanner` objects wrapping `System.in` will not change the fact that `System.in` is done (at EOF).

Comment: Could I user a wrapper to restart the application if it does not terminate normally?